# How to fix fitting with scipy.optimize.minimize for derivation condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, minimize

I am trying to fit a function `cav=p(T,x)` with the condition that the derivation after `x` of `cav` for `constant T` is always positive `dp/dx (for constant T) > 0`. The data of `x`, `T` and `p` are from excel sheets. `z` are my coefficients I am trying to get.

I've used the solution from here [Fitting with constraints on derivative Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52804492/fitting-with-constraints-on-derivative-python) as a template. Here is my code as it is right now with the providing error message:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "./data.xlsx"))

T = np.array(df['T'], dtype=float)
x = np.array(df['x'], dtype=float)
p = np.array(df['p'], dtype=float)
p_s = 67

def cav(z,T,x):  #my function
    return x * p_s + x * (1 - x) * (z[0] + z[1] * T + z[2] * T ** 2 + z[3] * x + z[4] * x * T + z[5] * x * T ** 2) * p_s

def resid(p,T,x):
    return ((p-cav(T,x))**2).sum()

def constr(z):
    return np.gradient(cav(z,x,T))

con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constr}

z0 = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0], dtype=float)
res = minimize(resid,z0, args=(p,T,x), method='cobyla',options={'maxiter':50000}, constraints=con1)
```

And the Error:

```
TypeError: resid() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I don't understand what exactly do I have to put in as arguments for the three `def`. Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are several issues with your code. I see `(p-cav(T,x))` while `cav` takes three arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you are passing 3 arguments to `resid` in addition to the initial guess `z0`.

Thus, the line which has to change is:

```
res = minimize(resid,z0, args=(T,x), method='cobyla',options={'maxiter':50000}, constraints=con1)
```

Another issue in your code is:

```
def resid(p,T,x):
    return ((p-cav(T,x))**2).sum()
```

Your method `cav` takes three arguments but you pass only two. So this probably should be changed to:

```
def resid(p,T,x):
    return ((p-cav(p,T,x))**2).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have done as you said but unfortunately I am getting the Error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,) (217,) ` I guess it has seomthing to do that the `len(T)`, `len(p)`, `len(x)` is 217 but the `len(z)` is 6 ? Any idea?

Comment: That is an issue which has to be raised in another question with more details about your data. On SO, you must refrain from asking multiple questions in a single post. If the question raised in your current issue is resolved then the question is deemed to be answered :)