# Least square approximation of a polynomial with a constraint on the derivative in Python

Tags: python, optimization, least-squares, constraint-programming, cvxpy

I'm trying to fit a polynomial of the third degree through a number of points. This could be a very simple problem when not constraining the derivative. I found some [promising solutions](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/solving-a-least-squares-problem-with-linear-constraints-in-python) using CVXPY to combine least squares with constraints but so far I'm not even able to solve the least-squares problem with CVXPY. I also posted this first on [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/33328/least-square-approximation-of-a-polynomial-with-a-constraint-on-the-derivative-i) but given the fact that it is more about the code Stack Overflow might be more appropriate. The code is below.

```py
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

# Problem data
x = np.array([100, 200, 300, 400, 500])
y = 2160 - 1.678571429 * x + 0.006785714 * x * x + 5.52692E-20 * x * x * x
print(x)
print(y)

# Constructing the problem
a = cp.Variable(1)
b = cp.Variable(1)
c = cp.Variable(1)
d = cp.Variable(1)
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(a + b * x + c * x * x + d * x * x * x - y))
prob = cp.Problem(objective)

# The optimal objective value is returned by `prob.solve()`.
result = prob.solve(solver=cp.SCS, eps=1e-5)
# The optimal value for x is stored in `x.value`.
print("a: ", a.value)
print("b: ", b.value)
print("c: ", c.value)
print("d: ", d.value)
print(a.value + b.value * x + c.value * x * x + d.value * x * x * x)
```

The result of all this is a = 831.67009518; b = 1.17905623; c = 0.00155167 and d = 2.2071452e-06. This gives the mediocre result of y_est = [967.29960654 1147.20547453 1384.63057033 1692.81776513 2085.00993011]. Given that it should be able to yield a perfect solution, the provided solution is not really satisfying to me.

Once this works, I should be able to add the constraints as follows.

```
# add constraint for derivative = 0 in x = 500
constraints = [b + 2 * c * 500 + 3 * d * 500 * 500 == 0]
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
```

I'm not bound to CVXPY, so alternative solutions are also welcome.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52817202/11751294) is a similar problem, which might help you.

Comment: @PéterLeéh, thanks for that hint. I've tried to rewrite my example using that code but also there it somehow won't converge to the perfect solution, even before applying the constraint. https://gist.github.com/danielsjf/837179175eacb1c76c1458c1a4ae619c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just have a problem with association and how numpy and cvxpy differ in what `*` means. For example, `c * x * x` is not the same as `x * x * c`. The former is of course `(c * x) * x` and the second `*` is a dot product and thus the expression is a scalar. The latter `(x * x) * c` is what you want, as it first does an element-wise multiply. After doing that you get a much more sensible solution :)

```
a:  [2159.91670117]
b:  [-1.67850696]
c:  [0.00678545]
d:  [-1.13389519e-12]
[2059.92053699 2095.63343178 2267.05537873 2574.18637106 3017.02640194]
```

Comment: This works indeed as expected. In hindsight, x**2 seems to work as well.